# SQL Server mode SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table that list students' grades per class.
I want a result set that looks like:

```
BIO...B
CHEM...C
```

Where the "B" and "C" are the modes for the class.
I can get a mode of all of the grades, but not sure how to get the mode per class

Comment: That's not the mode if you are talking in a statistical sense. The mode is the element which appears most often. In this case, both of your classes are bi-modal (A, C for Bio and B, D for Chem)

Comment: the result set i used is not related to the example table values i used

Comment: So do you truly want the mode?  Or, are you looking for the mean or median (hard to tell with two values) your example showed?

Comment: i want the mode, the value that occurs most often per class

Comment: and i'm using MS SQL Server, no built in MODE()

Comment: i think it involves using "TOP 1" and Count() and ordering, but I cannot figure out how yet

Comment: the grouping by class is throwing me

Comment: Please be clear on what you want: your description suggests median, but you refer to mode. The rollback in question is not helpful. It masks the OP's datasource.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here, something like this on SQL 2005/2008:

```
;WITH 
  Counts AS (
    SELECT ClassName, Grade, COUNT(*) AS GradeFreq 
    FROM Scores
    GROUP BY ClassName, Grade
    )
, Ranked AS (
    SELECT ClassName, Grade, GradeFreq
    , Ranking = DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ClassName ORDER BY GradeFreq DESC)
    FROM Counts
    )
SELECT * FROM Ranked WHERE Ranking = 1
```

or perhaps just:

```
;WITH Ranked AS (
  SELECT 
    ClassName, Grade
  , GradeFreq = COUNT(*)
  , Ranking = DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ClassName ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC)
  FROM Scores
  GROUP BY ClassName, Grade
  )
SELECT * FROM Ranked WHERE Ranking = 1
```

Comment: thanks, this will do it, but I am looking into how one does a UDF

Answer (score 2):

Use a GROUP BY clause.

```
SELECT className, ClassMode(className)
FROM Grades
GROUP BY className
```

Your Mode() function would have to be created of course, but it would be a simple function like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ClassMode(@ClassName varchar(50))
RETURNS varchar(2)
AS
BEGIN
    Declare @temp varchar(2)

    SELECT @temp = TOP 1 Grade, COUNT(*) Grades as frequency
    FROM Grades
    WHERE ClassName = @ClassName
    GROUP BY ClassName
    ORDER BY frequency DESC

    RETURN @temp
END
```

Comment: There is something missing in the function code isn't? It seems like the @ClassName is not used at all. I think it should chage the FROM clause to "FROM Grades where ClassName = @ClassName" or chage the GROUP BY clause to GROUP BY ClassName HAVING ClassName = @ClassName.

Also, the SELECT in the the main, could be simply Select distinct ClassName, ClassMode(ClassName) from Grades. This way you have one mode per ClassName. Or did I get this wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the catch on the function definition - was definitely missing the where/having.  As to the distinct, you could for sure do that - I was under the impression the OP was going to do it per student, so I doubt that simple query would accomplish what they need anyway, but you're right for the given example.

Comment: i need the mode per class, so you're saying i need to modify this UDF to make it work?