# Calculate mode in SQL

Tags: sql, mode

I have seen the answer from a previous post, which works fine but I have a small dilemma.
Taking the same scenario:

A table that list students' grades per class. I want a result set that looks like:

```
BIO...B 
CHEM...C
```

Where the "B" and "C" are the modes for the class and want to get the mode for the class.

Once I applied the below query, i got the following output:

```
Class | Score | Freq  |  Ranking 
2010  |   B   | 8     |    1 
2010  |   C   | 8     |    1 
2011  |   A   | 10    |    1 
2012  |   B   | 11    |    1
```

In 2010, I have two grades with the same frequency. What if..I just want to display the highest score, in this case will be "B". How can I achieve that? I would need to assign rankings to the letter grades, but I'm not sure how. Please advise.
Thanks.

Prior post:
[SQL Server mode SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045075/sql-server-mode-sql)

The query I used to retrieve the data was the answer from Peter:

```
;WITH Ranked AS ( 
SELECT 
    ClassName, Grade 
    , GradeFreq = COUNT(*) 
    , Ranking = DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ClassName ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) 
FROM Scores 
GROUP BY ClassName, Grade 
) 
SELECT * FROM Ranked WHERE Ranking = 1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change:

```
SELECT * FROM Ranked WHERE Ranking = 1
```

To:

```
SELECT Class, MIN(Grade) AS HighestGrade, Freq, Ranking
FROM Ranked
WHERE Ranking = 1
GROUP BY Class, Freq, Ranking
```

Comment: ok, I made the changed. It works fine. I'm just trying to digest the using of the MIN function in this query. Thanks.

Comment: The reason MIN() works is because 'higher' grades happen to be earlier in the alphabet. Since you want to return the better grade when two are tied for mode, finding the one closer to the start of the alphabet, via the min function, helps make this happen.