# TSQL mode (as in mean, median,mode)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to calculate the mode of a series of idsofInterest in a table, each with an accompanying valueOfInterest such:

```
idsOfInterest | valueOfInterest  
2             | 1A  
2             | 1A  
2             | 3B  
1             | 2A  
1             | 2C  
1             | 2A  
4             | 3B  
4             | 3B  
4             | 4C
```

but with millions of rows.
Each list of idOfInterest is sufficiently long that multimodes are not a problem. Ideally, I would like something like

```
idsOfInterest | modeValueOfInterest  
1             | 2A  
2             | 1A  
3             | 3C  
4             | 3B
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server mode SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045075/sql-server-mode-sql)

Comment: It is definitely a duplicate, but I've got to say that I like @Gordon Linoff's answer more than any on the other question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The mode is the most common value.  You can get this with aggregation and `row_number()`:

```
select idsOfInterest, valueOfInterest
from (select idsOfInterest, valueOfInterest, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by idsOfInterest order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from table t
      group by idsOfInterest, valueOfInterest
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```