# SQL Get MODE Instead of AVG

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure which returns me the average issue price of products. There will be multiple rows for each issue, and so I group by barcode, and also the number of stores that have inserted a row for this issue, and get the average of `IssuePrice` as this comes from user input:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetUnknownBarcodeReport]  
@Status INT,@StoreTypeID INT
AS
BEGIN

SELECT COUNT(StoreCode) AS [# Stores]
    ,MAX(IssueName) AS IssueName
    ,AVG(IssuePrice) AS IssuePrice
    ,Barcode
    ,Product.EAN13 AS [Matched Product Code]
    ,Product.Name AS [Matched Product Name]
    ,Product.MainCatagory AS [Product Catagory]
FROM UnknownBarcodes
LEFT JOIN Product on LEFT(UnknownBarcodes.Barcode,13) = Product.EAN13
WHERE UnknownBarcodeStatusID = @Status
AND LEN(Barcode) >= 10
AND StoreTypeID = @StoreTypeID
GROUP BY Barcode, Product.EAN13, Product.Name, Product.MainCatagory
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN @status = 1 THEN
        COUNT(StoreCode)
        WHEN @status = 2 THEN
        COUNT(StoreCode)
        WHEN @status = 3 THEN
        MAX(DateInserted)
    END DESC
 END
```

The same product can be reported multiple times and therefore have multiple rows, but sometimes users will enter different prices. If ten users all enter the same barcode and say the price is `100` then the `AVG(IssuePrice)` is also 100. However, if 9 enter `100`, and the last row is entered as `1` then the AVG changes to `90.1`

I would like to replace the `AVG` with the mathematical equivalent of `MODE` so that the above example would still return `100` because there are more `100`s reported than any other value. Is this possible in SQL?

To help re-create this, the script for the table is below:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UnknownBarcodes](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [StoreCode] [int] NULL,
    [DateInserted] [datetime] NULL,
    [StoreTypeID] [int] NULL,
    [Barcode] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [UnknownBarcodeStatusID] [int] NULL,
    [StatusDescription] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [IssueName] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [IssuePrice] [int] NULL,
    [AutoReported] [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_UnknownBarcodes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Product](
    [EAN13] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [MainCatagory] [varchar](100) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Product] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [EAN13] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[UnknownBarcodes] ([StoreCode],[DateInserted],[StoreTypeID],[Barcode],[UnknownBarcodeStatusID],[StatusDescription],[IssueName],[IssuePrice],[AutoReported]) VALUES (412,2015-07-15 08:01:03.817,1,'977096171301112',3,'Scanning issues regarding the reported unknown item','ASIAN TRADER FREE TRADE',200,1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[UnknownBarcodes] ([StoreCode],[DateInserted],[StoreTypeID],[Barcode],[UnknownBarcodeStatusID],[StatusDescription],[IssueName],[IssuePrice],[AutoReported]) VALUES (843,2015-07-15 08:01:03.817,1,'977096171301112',3,'Scanning issues regarding the reported unknown item','ASIAN TRADER FREE TRADE',10,1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[UnknownBarcodes] ([StoreCode],[DateInserted],[StoreTypeID],[Barcode],[UnknownBarcodeStatusID],[StatusDescription],[IssueName],[IssuePrice],[AutoReported]) VALUES (860,2015-07-15 08:01:03.817,1,'977096171301112',3,'Scanning issues regarding the reported unknown item','ASIAN TRADER FREE TRADE',10,1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[UnknownBarcodes] ([StoreCode],[DateInserted],[StoreTypeID],[Barcode],[UnknownBarcodeStatusID],[StatusDescription],[IssueName],[IssuePrice],[AutoReported]) VALUES (864,2015-07-15 08:01:03.817,1,'977096171301112',3,'Scanning issues regarding the reported unknown item','ASIAN TRADER FREE TRADE',10,1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[UnknownBarcodes] ([StoreCode],[DateInserted],[StoreTypeID],[Barcode],[UnknownBarcodeStatusID],[StatusDescription],[IssueName],[IssuePrice],[AutoReported]) VALUES (964,2015-07-15 08:01:03.817,1,'977096171301112',3,'Scanning issues regarding the reported unknown item','ASIAN TRADER FREE TRADE',10,1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[UnknownBarcodes] ([StoreCode],[DateInserted],[StoreTypeID],[Barcode],[UnknownBarcodeStatusID],[StatusDescription],[IssueName],[IssuePrice],[AutoReported]) VALUES (1061,2015-07-15 08:01:03.817,1,'977096171301112',3,'Scanning issues regarding the reported unknown item','ASIAN TRADER FREE TRADE',10,1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[UnknownBarcodes] ([StoreCode],[DateInserted],[StoreTypeID],[Barcode],[UnknownBarcodeStatusID],[StatusDescription],[IssueName],[IssuePrice],[AutoReported]) VALUES (1350,2015-07-15 08:01:03.817,1,'977096171301112',3,'Scanning issues regarding the reported unknown item','ASIAN TRADER FREE TRADE',10,1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[UnknownBarcodes] ([StoreCode],[DateInserted],[StoreTypeID],[Barcode],[UnknownBarcodeStatusID],[StatusDescription],[IssueName],[IssuePrice],[AutoReported]) VALUES (1375,2015-07-15 08:01:03.817,1,'977096171301112',3,'Scanning issues regarding the reported unknown item','ASIAN TRADER FREE TRADE',10,1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[UnknownBarcodes] ([StoreCode],[DateInserted],[StoreTypeID],[Barcode],[UnknownBarcodeStatusID],[StatusDescription],[IssueName],[IssuePrice],[AutoReported]) VALUES (1489,2015-07-15 08:01:03.817,1,'977096171301112',3,'Scanning issues regarding the reported unknown item','ASIAN TRADER FREE TRADE',10,1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[UnknownBarcodes] ([StoreCode],[DateInserted],[StoreTypeID],[Barcode],[UnknownBarcodeStatusID],[StatusDescription],[IssueName],[IssuePrice],[AutoReported]) VALUES (1531,2015-07-15 08:01:03.817,1,'977096171301112',3,'Scanning issues regarding the reported unknown item','ASIAN TRADER FREE TRADE',10,1)
```

You can see that the MODE of the above set should be `10` even though one row has a value of `200` which skews the `AVG`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TSQL mode (as in mean, median,mode)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23532027/tsql-mode-as-in-mean-median-mode)

Comment: Hi Pred, although this looks similar in terms of the word MODE, my data is also grouped by other columns, so I cannot see how to translate any part of that other problem to this question.

Comment: The theory is still the same, put it in a function or clr and have fun.

Comment: You have only provided the `CREATE TABLE` for one of the tables in your original script.  What does your `Product` table look like/contain?

Comment: Thanks Pred, but that isn't helpful. Please take a look at my code, and observe the way that it is grouped, and you will see that this isn't as simple as grabbing the mode from a flat list of values.

Comment: iamdave: I have added the Product table schema create instructions. Assume the table is empty for this purpose, as the point is to LEFT JOIN only as there are no rows in Product at this time.

Comment: iamdave, it will be an empty table. The left join means that the EAN13, the name, and the MainCatagory will return NULL values for this result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From:  http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/datadesign/calculating-mean-median-and-mode-with-sq/

**MODE**

> To Calculate the mode with sql server, we first need to get the counts for each value in the set. Then, we need to filter the data so that values equal to the count are returned.

```
Declare @Temp Table(Id Int Identity(1,1), Data Decimal(10,5))

Insert into @Temp Values(1)
Insert into @Temp Values(2)
Insert into @Temp Values(5)
Insert into @Temp Values(5)
Insert into @Temp Values(5)
Insert into @Temp Values(6)
Insert into @Temp Values(6)
Insert into @Temp Values(6)
Insert into @Temp Values(7)
Insert into @Temp Values(9)
Insert into @Temp Values(10)
Insert into @Temp Values(NULL)

SELECT TOP 1 with ties DATA
FROM   @Temp
WHERE  DATA IS Not NULL
GROUP  BY DATA
ORDER  BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

In your example the functional sql could be accomplished by a subquery:

```
(select top 1 IssuePrice from UnknownBarcodes barx where barx.BarCode = bar.Barcode group by barx.IssuePrice order by count(*) DESC ) IssuePrice_MODE
```

Total query:

```
declare @Status int, @StoreTypeId int;
set @Status = 3;
set @StoreTypeId = 1;
SELECT 
     COUNT(bar.StoreCode) AS [# Stores]
    ,MAX(bar.IssueName) AS IssueName
    ,AVG(bar.IssuePrice) AS IssuePrice
    ,(select top 1 IssuePrice from UnknownBarcodes barx where barx.BarCode = bar.Barcode group by barx.IssuePrice order by count(*) DESC ) IssuePrice_MODE
    ,bar.Barcode
    ,Product.EAN13 AS [Matched Product Code]
    ,Product.Name AS [Matched Product Name]
    ,Product.MainCatagory AS [Product Catagory]

FROM UnknownBarcodes bar
LEFT JOIN Product on LEFT(bar.Barcode,13) = Product.EAN13
WHERE bar.UnknownBarcodeStatusID = @Status
AND LEN(bar.Barcode) >= 10
AND bar.StoreTypeID = @StoreTypeID
GROUP BY bar.Barcode, Product.EAN13, Product.Name, Product.MainCatagory
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN @status = 1 THEN
        COUNT(bar.StoreCode)
        WHEN @status = 2 THEN
        COUNT(bar.StoreCode) 
        WHEN @status = 3 THEN
        MAX(bar.DateInserted) 
        end
     DESC
```

The query below might be a bit more efficient on large datasets since it restricts the results that have to be iterated

```
declare @Status int, @StoreTypeId int;
set @Status = 3;
set @StoreTypeId = 1;
with FirstQuery as (SELECT 

    *
FROM UnknownBarcodes bar
LEFT JOIN Product on LEFT(bar.Barcode,13) = Product.EAN13
WHERE bar.UnknownBarcodeStatusID = @Status
AND LEN(bar.Barcode) >= 10
AND bar.StoreTypeID = @StoreTypeID
)


select COUNT(StoreCode) AS [# Stores]
    ,MAX(IssueName) AS IssueName
    ,AVG(IssuePrice) AS IssuePrice
    ,Barcode
    ,(select top 1 IssuePrice from FirstQuery barx where barx.BarCode = FirstQuery.Barcode group by barx.IssuePrice order by count(*) DESC ) IssuePrice_MODE
    ,EAN13 AS [Matched Product Code]
    ,Name AS [Matched Product Name]
    ,MainCatagory AS [Product Catagory] 

    from FirstQuery

    GROUP BY Barcode, EAN13, Name, MainCatagory
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN @status = 1 THEN
        COUNT(StoreCode)
        WHEN @status = 2 THEN
        COUNT(StoreCode)
        WHEN @status = 3 THEN
        MAX(DateInserted)
    END DESC
```

Comment: Unfortunately this only deals with 10 flat rows, and not with my pre-grouped data. Please can you have a look at my code and see if there is any further help you can give?

Comment: If you can provide me with an sqlfiddle with populated columns I can. It's very hard to flesh out such a thing without being able to test it.

Comment: Thanks Micheal, I am trying to get sqlfiddle.com to create an example, but I am really struggling to oversome script errors on that site, even with the sample fiddles. I will update my post.

Comment: at least provide a create temp tables intruction set in your post that builds up a sample set.

Comment: Thanks for the help Michael, hopefully you will be able to sink your teeth into my post, or work out where I was going wrong in trying to create a SQLFfddle from my table and data instructional code...

Comment: hrmz... it's going into an infinite loop when i run your function. Msg 217, Level 16, State 1, Procedure GetUnknownBarcodeReport, Line 33
Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121818/discussion-between-michael-dibbets-and-russawesome).

Answer (score -1):

I have use inner query to calculate MODE.

```
SELECT COUNT(StoreCode) AS [# Stores]
    ,MAX(IssueName) AS IssueName
    ,AVG(IssuePrice) AS IssuePrice,
    (select top 1 issuePrice from [UnknownBarcodes] where ID = UnknownBarcodes.id group by IssuePrice having IssuePrice > 1) issuePrice_MODE
    ,Barcode
    ,Product.EAN13 AS [Matched Product Code]
    ,Product.Name AS [Matched Product Name]
    ,Product.MainCatagory AS [Product Catagory]
FROM UnknownBarcodes 
LEFT JOIN Product on LEFT(UnknownBarcodes.Barcode,13) = Product.EAN13
WHERE UnknownBarcodeStatusID = 3
AND LEN(Barcode) >= 10
AND StoreTypeID = 1
GROUP BY Barcode, Product.EAN13, Product.Name, Product.MainCatagory
```

Comment: This returns the MODE price for the whole table, and every single unique barcode in the table is now given the same MODE price.

Answer (score -1):

How does this work for what you are after?  No idea how well it will perform on larger datasets though:

```
;with cte as
(
select count(1) over (partition by b.IssueName
                                            ,p.EAN13
                                            ,p.Name
                                            ,p.MainCatagory
                                            ) as [# Stores]
        ,b.IssueName
        ,b.IssuePrice
        ,row_number() over (partition by b.IssueName
                                            ,p.EAN13
                                            ,p.Name
                                            ,p.MainCatagory
                            order by count(1) desc
                            ) as IssuePriceSort
        ,b.Barcode
        ,p.EAN13
        ,p.Name
        ,p.MainCatagory
from UnknownBarcodes as b
    left join Product as p
        on left(b.Barcode,13) = p.EAN13
where UnknownBarcodeStatusID = @Status
      and len(Barcode) >= 10
    and StoreTypeID = @StoreTypeID
group by b.Barcode
        ,b.IssueName
        ,b.IssuePrice
        ,p.EAN13
        ,p.Name
        ,p.MainCatagory
)
select [# Stores]
    ,[IssueName]
    ,[IssuePrice]
    ,[IssuePriceSort]
    ,[Barcode]
    ,[EAN13]
    ,[Name]
    ,[MainCatagory]
from cte
where IssuePriceSort = 1
```