# Calculate Mode in SQL Server for specific scenario as below

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, mode

I have two tables

```
Table 1

ColumnA ColumnB 
Account1  DeptA
Account2  DeptA
Account3  DeptA
Account4  DeptB
Account5  DeptB


Table 2

ColumnC  ColumnA  ColumnD  ColumnE(Date)
Deposit1 Account1 10
Deposit1 Account2 20
Deposit1 Account3 10
Deposit2 Account1 10
Deposit2 Account2 30
Deposit2 Account3  30
Deposit3 Account2 20
Deposit3 Account3 10

Deposit1 Account4 20
Deposit1 Account5 20
Deposit2 Account4 10
Deposit2 Account5 20



Expected Output
Count Mode(ColumnD) ColumnC   ColumnB  
2       10            Deposit1  Dept1    
2       30            Deposit2   Dept1
1       10            Deposit3   Dept1
2       20            Deposit1   Dept2
1       10            Deposit2   Dept2
```

I should be able to calculate Mode of ColumnD as below in SQL
From Table 1, 
For a given ColumnB (Group by ColumnB) for all the ColumnA in that group calculate the Mode for the same ColumnC which has values of ColumnD

If we observe expected output, the Dept1 has Account1, Account2 and Account3. If we observer Deposit1 has both in Dept1 and Dept2 but we need to calculate Mode based on given Dept1 and Dept2

Either Stored Procedure or SQL is helpful

Comment: where did columnb (result) come from? can only see DeptA and B

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TSQL mode (as in mean, median,mode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23532027/tsql-mode-as-in-mean-median-mode)

Comment: the columnB is from table 1, the foreign key ColumnA is associated in Table 2

Answer (score 2):

Calculating the mode in SQL is pretty easy -- just a `row_number()` operation with `group by`.  I think the following is what you are trying to do:

```
select tt.*
from (select t1.columnb, t2.columnc, t2.columnd, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by t1.columnb, t2.columnc order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from table2 t2 join
           table1 t1
           on t2.columna = t1.columna
      group by t1.columnb, t2.columnc, t2.columnd
     ) tt
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Other than the missing group by in the subquery, you probably also need to partition by t2.columnc in the row_number() partition.

Comment: How can I use date when there is count 1 for ColumnD for each ColumnC ? in that case I should be able to pick the recent most value for Mode

Comment: @TechJump When there is no MODE, the convention is that the mode should be represented as a min/max range of the population

Comment: select tt.*
    from (select t1.columnb, t2.columnc, t2.columnd, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by t1.columnb, t2.columnc order by 
    count(*) ,t2.columne desc) as seqnum
      from table2 t2 join
           table1 t1
           on t2.columna = t1.columna
      group by t1.columnb, t2.columnc, t2.columnd,t2.columne
     ) tt
    where seqnum = 1;  

Does this seems correct?

Comment: @JohnCappelletti  I have a specific case for it, when there is no Mode, I should be picking recent most value as Mode.

Comment: @TechJump . . . Your output doesn't have a date.  Changing the question would be rude, because that would invalidate this answer.  I would suggest that you ask another question, if a simple suggestion doesn't help.  Your suggestion of including the date in the `order by` fixed one problem.  You can also include something like `max(columne)` in the inner `select`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks for suggestion, the solution works  ordering with date as desc after count in the sql