# T-SQL get the maximum of a string/varchar field

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with fields like this:

| Name | Location | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | UK | 1-1-2023 |
| John | UK | 1-2-2023 |
| John | UK | 1-3-2023 |
| John | Spain | 1-4-2023 |
| John | Spain | 1-5-2023 |
| John | UK | 1-6-2023 |
| Frank | USA | 1-1-2023 |
| Frank | USA | 1-2-2023 |
| Frank | Brazil | 1-3-2023 |
| Frank | Brazil | 1-4-2023 |
| Frank | USA | 1-5-2023 |
| Frank | Brazil | 1-6-2023 |
| Frank | Brazil | 1-7-2023 |

What I ultimately want to get is the Name and most frequent location, per name, regardless of date.

So output should be:

| Name | Location |
| --- | --- |
| John | UK |
| Frank | Brazil |

What I have now seems convoluted, but its basically:

```
select Table.Name, Table.Location
from Table
join (
      select Name, MAX(CountLocation) MaxCountLoc
      from (
            select Name, Location, COUNT(*) CountLocation from Table group by Name, Location
           ) MaxLocation
      group by Name
) MaxCountLocation
on Table.Name=MaxCountLocation.Name
group by Table.Name, Table.Name
having COUNT(*) = MaxCountLocation.MaxCountLoc
```

I think I'm just having some brain fog as there has to be a simpler way to do this, right? Thanks!

Comment: What do you want if there's a tie?

Comment: Let's go with return both

Comment: You don't want the "maximum" you want the *mode*. Does this answer your question? [TSQL mode (as in mean, median,mode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23532027/tsql-mode-as-in-mean-median-mode)

Comment: ah, yeah row_number for mode may very well work. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of *rank* to assign ranks based on the count in each partitioned window (as you want to include all names with the same highest count):

```
with r as (
  select *, rank() over(partition by name order by Count(*) desc) rnk,
  from t
  group by name, location
)
select Name, Location
from r
where rnk = 1;
```